# static в глобальной области видимости

Tags: c++, c

Если я объявляю `static`-функцию в глобальной области видимости, то она доступна только в этом файле, и её `extern` уже не получить. Если `static`-переменная будет внутри функции, то это понятно, память один раз выделяется за всё время пользования программы. Но я что-то не пойму, что значит `static` в глобальной области видимости.

Я думаю что `static`-переменная в глобальной области, это то же что и функция в глобальной области, что эту переменную нельзя использовать `extern` в другом файле. Потому что глобальная переменная и так как `static` выделяется один раз.

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правы. Если идентификатор объекта или функции объявлен в области видимости файла (англ. file scope) со спецификатором хранения `static`, то этот идентификатор будет иметь *внутреннюю линковку* (англ. internal linkage) и не будет «виден» внутри других единиц трансляции.

Например, имеем следующую ситуацию:

**`a.c`:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "b.h"

int main(void)
{
    extern int variable;

    set_value(1000);

    printf("%d\n", variable);
}
```

**`b.c`:**

```
#include "b.h"

int variable;

void set_value(const int v)
{
    variable = v;
}
```

**`b.h`:**

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

void set_value(const int);

#endif
```

Если внутри `b.c` объявить `variable` с ключевым словом `static`, то получим ошибку линковки:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccJguPPE.o: in function `main':
a.c:(.text+0x10): undefined reference to `variable'
```